# CodeViser JTag Debugger: how it knows u-boot's relocated offset in RAM?

Tags: u-boot, armv8, jtag

I am currently using CodeViser Jtag debugger connecting to a FPGA for debugging firmware for an Armv8 processor. From within the CodeViser GUI client (called `CVD64` on windows) I can set break points at absolute addresses.

One thing I noticed that, when I set a break point at some functions in u-boot, I use the address as shown in `u-boot.map`, which reflects the initial loading address of u-boot. In my case, the u-boot text section is initially loaded to `0x20408000`.

When the break point I set hits, the actual address the PC stops is not what I specified from GUI, but another address, which is the relocated one (i.e., after u-boot relocation).

For example, I set break point from GUI at `0x20413040`, and `CVD64` stops at `0x207ae040`, the offset is `0x39b000`. This offset is exactly the same as u-boot itself printed to serial port:

```
Relocation Offset is: 0039b000
Relocating to 207a3000, new gd at 2075edf0, sp at 2075ede0
```

This is nice. I am just wondering how CVD64 knows the relocate offset and automatically place HLT instruction in relocated address?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you set the breakpoint before relocation? Breakpoints can either be managed by special hardware registers of a CPU or by adding a breakpoint instruction in the code. In the latter case this instruction may be relocated as well.

Comment: @Xypron I set the breakpoint before the program run, so it's before the relocation. So it's possible that the HLT instruction has already been inserted before relocation, and a relocation simply also copied the HLT instructions.